# Pytorch schedule learning rate

Tags: optimization, pytorch, learning-rate

I am trying to re-implement one paper, which suggests to adjust the learning rate as below:

> The learning rate is decreased by a **factor** of the regression value with patience epochs 10 on the **change value** of 0.0001.

Should I use the `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau()`?

I am not sure what value should I pass to each parameter.

1. Is the **change value** in the statement denotes to the parameter **threshold**?
2. Is the *factor* in the statement denotes to the parameter **factor**?

Answer (score 20):

`torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau` is indeed what you are looking for. I summarized all of the important stuff for you.

`mode=min`: lr will be reduced when the quantity monitored has stopped decreasing

`factor`: factor by which the learning rate will be reduced

`patience`: number of epochs with no improvement after which learning rate will be reduced

`threshold`: threshold for measuring the new optimum, to only focus on significant changes (change value). Say we have `threshold=0.0001`, if loss is 18.0 on epoch *n* and loss is 17.9999 on epoch *n+1* then we have met our criteria to multiply the current learning rate by the `factor`.

```
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, mode='min',
    factor=0.1, patience=10, threshold=0.0001, threshold_mode='abs')

for epoch in range(20):
    # training loop stuff
    loss = criterion(...)
    scheduler.step(loss)
```

You can check more details in the documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau

Comment: Is it possible to decrease the learning_rate by minus a constant value instead by a factor?

Comment: For `mode` what quantity is being monitored, the optimizer? or the loss function?

Answer (score 4):

Pytorch has many ways to let you reduce the learning rate. It is quite well explained here:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate

@Antonino DiMaggio explained ReduceOnPlateau quite well. I just want to complement the answer to reply to the comment of @Yan-JenHuang:

> Is it possible to decrease the learning_rate by minus a constant value instead by a factor?

First of all, you should be very careful to avoid negative values of lr! Second, subtracting a value of the learning rate is not common practice. But in any case...

You have first to make a custom lr scheduler (I modified the code of LambdaLR https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.html#LambdaLR):

```
torch.optim.lr_scheduler import _LRScheduler

class SubtractLR(_LRScheduler):
    def __init__(self, optimizer, lr_lambda, last_epoch=-1, min_lr=e-6):
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.min_lr = min_lr  # min learning rate > 0 

        if not isinstance(lr_lambda, list) and not isinstance(lr_lambda, tuple):
            self.lr_lambdas = [lr_lambda] * len(optimizer.param_groups)
        else:
            if len(lr_lambda) != len(optimizer.param_groups):
                raise ValueError("Expected {} lr_lambdas, but got {}".format(
                    len(optimizer.param_groups), len(lr_lambda)))
            self.lr_lambdas = list(lr_lambda)
        self.last_epoch = last_epoch
        super(LambdaLR, self).__init__(optimizer, last_epoch)

    def get_lr(self):
        if not self._get_lr_called_within_step:
            warnings.warn("To get the last learning rate computed by the scheduler, "
                          "please use `get_last_lr()`.")

        return [(max(base_lr - lmbda(self.last_epoch), self.min_lr)
                for lmbda, base_lr in zip(self.lr_lambdas, self.base_lrs)] # reduces the learning rate
```

Than you can use it in your training.

```
 lambda1 = lambda epoch: e-4 # constant to subtract from lr
 scheduler = SubtractLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=[lambda1])
 for epoch in range(100):
     train(...)
     validate(...)
     scheduler.step()
```

```
 lambda1 = lambda epoch: epoch * e-6 # increases the value to subtract lr proportionally to the epoch
 scheduler = SubtractLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=[lambda1])
 for epoch in range(100):
     train(...)
     validate(...)
     scheduler.step()
```

You can also modify the code of `ReduceLROnPlateau` to subtract the learning rate instead of mutiplying it. Your should change this line `new_lr = max(old_lr * self.factor, self.min_lrs[i])` to something like `new_lr = max(old_lr - self.factor, self.min_lrs[i])`. You can take a look at the code yourself: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.html#ReduceLROnPlateau

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement for the above answer for ReduceLROnPlateau that threshold also has modes(rel|abs) in lr scheduler for pytorch (at least for vesions>=1.6), and the default is 'rel' which means if your loss is 18, it will change at least 18*0.0001=0.0018 to be recognized as an improvement. So, watch out the threshold mode as well.