# StableBaslines3 - Can I adaptively decrease learning rate?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines, learning-rate

I am working in the StableBaselines3 package. I know that I can make learning rate schedule by inputting a function to the "learning_rate" argument. However, what I want to be able to do is adaptively decrease the learning rate. Instead of fine-tuning a new LR schedule for every situation, I want the learning rate to "automatically" decrease a certain amount when the performance hits a plateau/stops increasing.

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108131/pytorch-schedule-learning-rate) explores how to do this in PyTorch. I know SB3 is built on PyTorch, so is this same function usable somehow in SB3?

Is there any elegant way to do this in SB3? Or would I have to just stop the training periodically, run a check, implement new LR, run again etc.?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it myself, but I'm deaing with SB3 callbacks these days and it should be possible to implement a custom callback that monitors the performance and then changes the model's learning rate based on that.

> You can use callbacks to access internal state of the RL model during
> training. It allows one to do monitoring, auto saving, model
> manipulation, progress bars, …

See here https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/callbacks.html